# Is it possible to avoid styling a certain <span> when styling their parent?

Tags: html, css

I have a price list. It's a table with a couple small explainers called `<span class="small-text">` for some of the services.
The table also has some headers, `<td class="service-header">` for grouping the services.

On a few occasions the explainer `<span>` is found inside the header `<td>`, and I can't find the simple solution (I do believe it exist) for excluding `.small-text` when styling `.service-header`.

I'm pretty sure that `:not(.small-text)` fits in somewhere in the header styling. I just can't figure.

```css
tr {
  font-family : Arial;
  height      : 40px;
  }
.small-text { 
  font-size   : .8em !important; 
  color       : #6e7271;
  }
.price-table .service-header {
  font-family : Lora;
  font-weight : 600;
  font-size   : 1.5em;
  padding-top : 30px;
  line-height : 1;
  }
```

```html
<table class="price-table">
  <thead><tr class=""><th></th><th></th></tr></thead>
  <tbody>
<!-- … --> 
    <tr>
      <td class="service">
        Rotfylling av molarer
        <br>
        <span class="small-text">
          Pris per halvtime.
        </span>
      </td>
      <td class="price">5800 kr</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <!-- This one -->
      <td class="service-header">
        Protetikk
        <br>
        <span class="small-text">
          Alle priser inkl. bedøvelse og tannteknikk.
        </span>
      </td>
      <td class="price"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="service">Krone fullkeramisk</td>
      <td class="price">6900 kr</td>
    </tr>
<!-- … --> 
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you wanting to style the spans inside the header the same way as the others? Or do you just want to NOT apply the style when they are inside the header? If the latter simply try: `.small-text:not(.service-header .small-text) { . . . }`

Comment: Yep. I want ```.small-text``` to ignore the styling of ```.service-header```

Comment: Ahh you want it to ignore the styling of the header. Gotcha.

Comment: use `rem` unit ?

Comment: @MisterJojo For font-size? Yeah but I wan't to avoid font-family, font-weight etc. also

Comment: Yeah, you might want to override the styles you want specific in your span and in your header both. Something like: ```.small-text { 
  font-size: 11px !important; 
  color: #6e7271;
  font-family: Arial !important;
  font-weight: normal;
}``` because otherwise the child element will inherit all other non-specified styles from its parent.

Comment: @HanletEscaño Thanks, yes that's excactly my fallback too (if a solution to this question doesn't exist)

Comment: there is no way, css is a hierarchical system, so children inherit their parent style, if you want independent styles put your first lines in spans too, so they don't have that relationship anymore

Comment: Idk if you'll  find a way of doing something like that with just css (maybe with sass). You want your styles to behave independently tho, so it doesn't matter where you put that span it will always works. So having a font family, and font-weight, etc is probably a good idea if you will use it everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it can be done with CSS *only*.
Please check the link for more info: [MDN: Cascade and inheritance (inherite, initial, unset)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Cascade_and_inheritance).

You can do that using JavaScript:

- 1. We remove the the `.service-header > span.small-text` *class name `.small-text`*. because the `em unit` will cause a problem. since it's a relative unit passed on its *parent*.
- 2. We take the `.service > span.small-text` in *JavaScript* **and** the `span` element in the `.service-header` element (The one we changed eariler).
- 3. We pass both as an argument to a function (`copyNodeStyle`) that simply takes the `.service > span.small-text` style and sets the same for `.service-header > span`.

The `Combinator Selectors` here matters! Moving `elements` that we selected as a *child* to another *parent* will cause bugs.

```js
var headerSmallText = document.querySelector('.service-header span');
var smallText = document.querySelector('.service .small-text');


function copyNodeStyle(sourceNode, targetNode) {
  var computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(sourceNode);
  Array.from(computedStyle).forEach(function (key) {
    return targetNode.style.setProperty(key, computedStyle.getPropertyValue(key), computedStyle.getPropertyPriority(key));
  });
}

copyNodeStyle(smallText, headerSmallText);
```

```css
tr {
  font-family : Arial;
  height      : 40px;
 }
.small-text { 
  font-size   : .8em !important; 
  color       : #6e7271;
  }

.service-header {
  font-family : Lora;
  font-weight : 600;
  font-size   : 1.5em;
  padding-top : 30px;
  line-height : 1;
 }
```

```html
<table class="price-table">
  <thead><tr class=""><th></th><th></th></tr></thead>
  <tbody>
<!-- … --> 
    <tr>
      <td class="service">
        Rotfylling av molarer
        <br>
        <span class="small-text">
          Pris per halvtime.
        </span>
      </td>
      <td class="price">5800 kr</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <!-- This one -->
      <td class="service-header">
        Protetikk
        <br>
        <span>
          Alle priser inkl. bedøvelse og tannteknikk.
        </span>
      </td>
      <td class="price"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="service">Krone fullkeramisk</td>
      <td class="price">6900 kr</td>
    </tr>
<!-- … --> 
  </tbody>
</table>
```